# Anagram code without using a loop

Tags: ruby

```
dictionary = ['acres', 'cares', 'Cesar', 'races', 'smelt', 'melts', 'etlsm']

def anagrams_for(word, array)
    matches = []
    array.each do |x|
        if word.downcase.chars.sort == x.downcase.chars.sort
            matches.push(x)
        end
    end
    puts matches
end
```

If the input word is in the dictionary, it should be in the the returned array.

The list should be case-insensitive.

```
anagrams_for('acres', dictionary) # => ['acres', 'cares', 'Cesar', 'races']
anagrams_for('ACRES', dictionary) # => ['acres', 'cares', 'Cesar', 'races']
anagrams_for('Cesar', dictionary) # => ['acres', 'cares', 'Cesar', 'races']
```

Although `"sacre"` is not in the dictionary, several words in the dictionary are anagrams of `"sacre"`.

```
anagrams_for('sacre', dictionary) # => ['acres', 'cares', 'Cesar', 'races']
```

Neither the input word nor the words in the dictionary need to be valid English words.

```
anagrams_for('etlsm', dictionary) # => ['smelt', 'melts', 'etlsm']
anagrams_for('unicorn', dictionary) # => []
```

Is there a method that does not require looping to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1):

```
def anagram?(word, other)
  word.downcase.chars.sort == other.downcase.chars.sort
end

def anagrams_for(word, array)
  array.select { |other_word| anagram?(word, other_word) }
end
```

I don't know if that is what you are looking for since `select` **will** loop through the array anyway.

Comment: Thank you, that is very elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use hash in this case

```
def get_dictionary_hash(dictionary)
  exp = Hash.new{|k, v| k[v] = []}
  dictionary.each{|s| exp[s.downcase.chars.sort] << s}
  exp
end

def anagrams_for(word, dictionary)
  dictionary[word.downcase.chars.sort] || []
end
```

test

```
dictionary = ['acres', 'cares', 'Cesar', 'races', 'smelt', 'melts', 'etlsm']

dictionary_h = get_dictionary_hash(dictionary)

['acres', 'ACRES', 'Cesar', 'sacre', 'etlsm', 'unicorn'].each do |word|
  puts word
  p anagrams_for(word, dictionary_h)
end

# => acres
# => ["acres", "cares", "Cesar", "races"]
# => ACRES
# => ["acres", "cares", "Cesar", "races"]
# => Cesar
# => ["acres", "cares", "Cesar", "races"]
# => sacre
# => ["acres", "cares", "Cesar", "races"]
# => etlsm
# => ["smelt", "melts", "etlsm"]
# => unicorn
# => []
```

I hope this helps